# I need sticky day for my chat app same like whatsapp message screen in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

Hi react native devs need help for my chat app. I need to render day in sticky position same like whatsapp message screen. when user scroll in message screen day will be show on top of screen...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31DHM.png)

Please check the image. when user scroll day and date show on scroll thanks. Day and date is shown but i need when screen scroll its goes to top.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [gifted chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat). It is a chat component with the feature you a looking for. 
If you dont want to use [gifted chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) you can use CSS to make a component that displays the day
 "float" above others with: [`position:"absolute"`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#position) while in the same container(`view`) as the component it should "float" over.

Comment: I am using gifted chat but render day is working but I wants when i scroll the page each day float to top.

Comment: In gifted chat render day is use for showing day but I need to float it when scroll same like whatsapp